# Specific part of background in a plot - outside plotting area

Tags: plotting

I need to add a rectangle to my plot that includes being behind the ticks but not the label of my graph.

I know with `Prolog`you can add a rectangle, like with the code:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, Prolog -> {Red, Rectangle[Scaled[{0., 0.8}], Scaled[{1, 1}]]}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]

But I need the rectangle to go beyond where it is now, to be wider, and  actually be behind the number 8 (but not behind the frame label) and go passed the frame a little bit on other side too. With `Background` I could cover the whole thing but I am only interested in that rectangle and need the rest of the picture to remain backgroundless.

Is it at all posible?
Thank you!

Comment: Interestingly, I just got here and had a look at the images. I first saw the images in the two answers and thought, "ugh, this looks ugly with the rectangle extending outside the box". Then I saw the nice image in your question. And finally I was surprised to learn that you actually asked for the style in the answers!

Comment: Yes. The graph I am trying to make is obviously way more complicated than that but that's what I was looking for. It serves to hightlight other graphics that will be displayed along side this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping)->[`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) and extend the [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle):

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3},
    Prolog -> {Red, Rectangle[Scaled[{-.03,.8}],Scaled[{1.03,1}]]},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {"x","y"},
    PlotRangeClipping -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had tried negative values of `Scaled` but it didnt do anything!

Comment: My plot is a  `ListLinePlot` of imported data. The data beyond the range is showing becuase the plotting area hasnt been clipped. Is there any way to hide it that you know of?

Answer (score 4):

Here is alternative way to do it.

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{-0.1, 7.8}, {3, 9}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 9}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very simple! Thanks!